# UserWarning: Module fipy was already imported

Tags: python, fipy

I get the following error when I try to import fipy from the python prompt.

```
>>>import fipy    
/home/jana/Builds/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fipy/__init__.py:34: UserWarning: Module     fipy was already imported from /home/jana/Builds/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fipy/__init__.py, but /home/jana/Builds/lib/python2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path 
from pkg_resources import get_distribution, DistributionNotFound
```

I used stow while installing fipy. I looked into similar errors here, but they referred to imports from two different directories. I have the same path repeated in the error message.